# Determining the smallest number of cards which ensure a winning strategy

Tags: optimization, card-games

Given a card game:

Person $A$ and Person $B$ are on the same team, Person $C$ is their adversary. Person A provides $k$ identical empty cards and while Person $B$ is not looking, Person $C$ writes onto each card a number $1-2021$, repetitions allowed and Person A then turns all the cards except one of his choosing upside down so that the numbers are not visible. Then Person $B$ returns and points to card saying its value. Persons $AB$ win if $B$ can guess correctly, $C$ wins if they can write such numbers that $B$ is unable to do so.

The task is to determine the smallest possible $k\ge 2$ such that Person $A$ and Person $B$ have a winning strategy (i.e. it is always possible for Person $A$ and Person $B$ to decide on a strategy within the rules that always leads to victory)

I have played around with different $k$ and different card number ranges but I haven't been able to deduce anything substantial. Another interesting question would be : how does the answer vary with the range of numbers $C$ can write? That could perhaps lead to an elegant solution, but I am not sure.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "Person A and Person B are the same player" : Clarification requested.  Seems like you intend that A and B are different humans, but on the same Team, and the victory or loss goes to the Team.  Is this correct?

Comment: Further clarification requested: "Winning strategy" : Does this represent that AB has a greater than 50% chance of winning, or that AB has a 100% chance of winning?

Comment: Explain how "Person A and Person B are the same player" *and* that "Person A provides... while person B is not looking."  Wow.  Wrap your mind around *that*!

Comment: Is this problem from a competition? If so, which one? If not, where is the problem from?

Comment: Person A and Person B are on the same team yes. Another way to think about it would be A and B conducting a magic trick for C and the question being when can they be sure that the trick will go well. Winning strategy means that they can always play such that they will win regardless of the moves of C.